# What requests do browsers' "F5" and "Ctrl + F5" refreshes generate?

Tags: http, browser, caching, cross-browser, refresh

Is there a standard for what actions <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> trigger in web browsers?

I once did experiment in IE6 and Firefox 2.x. The <kbd>F5</kbd>  refresh would trigger a HTTP request sent to the server with an `If-Modified-Since` header, while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> would not have such a header. In my understanding, <kbd>F5</kbd>  will try to utilize cached content as much as possible, while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> is intended to abandon all cached content and just retrieve all content from the servers again.

But today, I noticed that in some of the latest browsers (Chrome, IE8) it doesn't work in this way anymore. Both <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> send the `If-Modified-Since` header.

So how is this supposed to work, or (if there is no standard) how do the major browsers differ in how they implement these refresh features?

Comment: FWIW: while this certainly *could* be a Super User topic, and may even have been intended as somewhat end-user-focused when originally asked, at this point it has been both answered and referenced by programmers and web developers and should probably be left here. SU has several other, more end-user-oriented versions of this already, and doesn't need it...

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1854/

Comment: I may be crazy but I think `ALT+F5` does the same as `CTRL+F5`.

Comment: @ashleedawg According to my research (see table in my answer) only Opera 9 does something with ALT+F5 but not CTRL+F5, while all other tested browsers does something with CTRL+F5 but not ALT+F5. This is on Windows. What OS and browser was you using?

Answer (score 332, accepted):

Generally speaking:

<kbd>F5</kbd> may give you the same page even if the content is changed, because it may load the page from cache. But <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> forces a cache refresh, and will guarantee that if the content is changed, you will get the new content.

Comment: Thi is accurate, but note that while Ctrl+F5 will cause the browser to throw out the cache and request a new from the server, the server may ignore the no-cache header and serve a server side cached page.  Thus even Ctrl+F5 may return an old version of the page if the server ignores the no-cache header.

Comment: F5 wil refresh the page - CTRL+F5 will do 'hard' refresh.

Comment: Also mention, that Ctrl-F5 will submit a form, if given.

Comment: Ok, so if you hit ctrl+f5 you tell your browser not to use its cache, but what happens in subsequent requests to the same page? I mean, can you see older versions of the page after you´ve seen the oldest one? If i´m seeing version 1 of the page because its cached but theres already version 2 available, i understand that hitting ctrl+f5 will make me see version2. Then i close my browser and open that page again, ¿do i see version 1 or i still see version2? Thanks.

Answer (score 536):

It is up to the browser, but they behave in similar ways.

<kbd>F5</kbd> usually updates the page only if it is modified. Modern browsers send `Cache-Control: max-age=0` to tell any cache the maximum amount of time a resource is considered fresh, relative to the time of the request.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> is used to force an update, disregarding any cache. Modern browsers send `Cache-Control: no-cache` and `Pragma: No-cache`

If I remember correctly, it was Netscape that was the first browser to add support for cache-control by adding `Pragma: No-cache` when you pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd>.

```
┌───────────┬──────────────┬─────┬─────────────────┬──────────────────────────────┐
│ Version 4 │      F5      │  R  │      CLICK      │ Legend:                      │
│2021 MAY 19├──┬──┬──┬──┬──┼──┬──┼──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┤ C = Cache-Control: no-cache  │
│           │  │S │C │A │A │C │C │  │S │C │A │A │C │ I = If-Modified-Since        │
│           │  │H │T │L │L │T │T │  │H │T │L │L │T │ M = Cache-Control: max-age=0 │
│           │  │I │R │T │T │R │R │  │I │R │T │T │R │ N = Not tested               │
│           │  │F │L │  │G │L │L │  │F │L │  │G │L │ P = Pragma: No-cache         │
│           │  │T │  │  │R │  │+ │  │T │  │  │R │+ │ - = ignored                  │
│           │  │  │  │  │  │  │S │  │  │  │  │  │S │                              │
│           │  │  │  │  │  │  │H │  │  │  │  │  │H │ With 'CLICK' I refer to a    │
│           │  │  │  │  │  │  │I │  │  │  │  │  │I │ mouse click on the browsers  │
│           │  │  │  │  │  │  │F │  │  │  │  │  │F │ refresh-icon.                │
│           │  │  │  │  │  │  │T │  │  │  │  │  │T │                              │
│           │  │  │  │  │  │  │  │  │  │  │  │  │  │ 1: Version 3.0.6 sends I     │
├───────────┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┤    and C, but 3.1.6 opens    │
│Brave 1.24 │M │CP│CP│- │- │M │CP│M │CP│CP│M │CP│CP│    the page in a new tab,    │
├───────────┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┤    making a normal request   │
│Chrome 1   │MI│MI│MI│- │- │MI│- │MI│MI│MI│MI│MI│N │    with only I.              │
│Chrome 6   │MI│CP│CP│- │- │MI│CP│MI│CP│CP│MI│- │N │ 2: Version 10.62 does        │
│Chrome 90  │M │CP│CP│- │- │M │CP│M │CP│CP│M │CP│CP│    nothing. 9.61 might do C  │
├───────────┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┤    unless it was a typo in   │
│Edge 90    │M │CP│CP│- │- │M │CP│M │CP│CP│M │CP│CP│    my old table.             │
├───────────┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┤ 3: Opens the currernt tab in │
│Firefox 3.x│MI│- │CP│- │- │MI│CP│MI│CP│1 │M │MI│N │    a new tab, but does not   │
│Firefox 89 │M │- │CP│- │M │M │CP│M │CP│3 │M │M │3 │    refresh the page if it is │
├───────────┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┤    cached in the browser.    │
│MSIE 8, 7  │I │- │C │- │I │I │  │I │I │C │I │I │N │                              │
├───────────┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┤                              │
│Opera 10, 9│C │- │- │2 │- │C │- │C │C │C │C │- │N │                              │
│Opera 76   │M │CP│CP│- │- │M │- │M │CP│CP│M │CP│CP│                              │
├───────────┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──────────────────────────────┤
│                    https://stackoverflow.com/a/385491/36866                     │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

**Note about Chrome 6.0.472**: If you do a forced reload (like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd>) it behaves like the url is internally marked to always do a forced reload. The flag is cleared if you go to the address bar and press enter.

Comment: Any chance you could add SHIFT-ClickRefreshButton to this table?

Comment: BTW: Very nice job color-coding the key like that.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn: Updated the table with click on the refresh button. Got to love ASCII graphic tables, don't you? The color-coding was is just a side-effect of the code color-coding.

Comment: Can't you do it as a proper HTML table?

Comment: FYI - this answer has actually been referenced on the chrome development/bug tracking boards: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1906

Comment: @Kyle: Thanks for correcting my spelling. @Kip: Thank you very much for the information about the chrome bug tracking. That made my day!

Comment: @John Topley: Tables isn't allowed, so the answer is no.

Comment: Great work on this table - this belongs on quirksmode. +1. I wonder if there's also variation in what headers are used to request resources within the refreshed page, such as images, stylesheets, etc...

Comment: @James Hart: Thank you! This is the result I got after testing with a html document with an external script, css and image: For `FF` (4.0.1@win32) and `MSIE`(8.0.6001.18702@win32) it's the same type of request. `Chrome` (11.0.696.68@win32) also does the same, but if you force a reload (CTRL-F5) it behaves like an internal flag is set and if you press F5 again the HTML-document is retrieved with `MP` and all other with `IM`. Se the note above in the answer. `Opera` (11.01 1190@win32) does `C` for the HTML-document and `I` for the included resources.

Comment: I believe Chrome has updated its shift-refresh behavior as of 11 or 12 or so. Could we can get an update? Thanks!

Comment: @Paul Irish: I will check if they have changed it in a few days. BTW you noticed the note about chrome 6?

Comment: @PaulIrish 10 years later, the table is updated. :)

Answer (score 70):

I've implemented cross-browser compatible page to test [browser's refresh behavior](https://web.archive.org/web/20130111203313/http://podlipensky.com/2012/03/behind-refresh-button/) (here is [the source code](https://github.com/podlipensky/RefreshButton/)) and get results similar to @some, but for modern browsers:

[image]

Comment: The links on your page are broken, I fixed the link on the answer, but a lot of the links from that page are broken. http://podlipensky.com/examples/refreshbutton/index.html , http://podlipensky.com/post/2012/02/27/How-to-check-if-browser-caching-disabled.aspx

Comment: Sorry, about that - doing blog migration. Links will be fixed ASAP, for now - please go to github repository and download examples.

Comment: The links are still broken. Migration not finished?

Comment: Can you please update your answer with current version of the browsers, especially mobile and desktop Safari, @PavelPodlipensky?

Answer (score 10):

At least in Firefox (v3.5), cache seems to be *disabled* rather than simply cleared. If there are multiple instances of the same image on a page, it will be transferred multiple times. That is also the case for `img` tags that are added subsequently via Ajax/JavaScript.

So in case you're wondering why the browser keeps downloading the same little icon a few hundred times on your auto-refresh Ajax site, it's because you initially loaded the page using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

IE7/8/9 seem to behave differently depending on whether the page has focus or not.

If you click on the page and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> then "Cache-Control: no-cache" is included in the request headers. If you click in the Location/Address bar then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

When user press <kbd>F5</kbd> although new request goes to web server and get a responce for the request as well. But when the responce header is Parsed it check the required information in browser cache. If the required information in cache has not expired then that information is restored from in cache itself.

When user click on <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> even then new request goes to web server and get a responce. But this time when the responce header is Parsed it do not check any required information in cache, and bring all updated information form server only.