# Firefox addon to remove cache and cookies of one domain?

Tags: firefox, cookies, firefox-addon, browser-cache

I use Firefox to develop a web site and at the same time to browse the web, read my gmail, etc.

The problem is every now and then I need to delete the cache and or remove the cookies of the web app, but I want to stayed logged in in the other web pages I am visiting.

Do you know a Firefox plugin (or Firefox trick) that can help with this issue?

Comment: Super User is the way to go...

Comment: Super User, as in http://superuser.com/questions/173210/how-can-i-clear-a-single-site-from-the-cache-in-firefox.  ;)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`Preferences` → `Privacy` → `remove individual cookies`

They are grouped by domain, and you can eliminate all cookies from selected domain with one click.

[image]

Update:
`Option` → `Privacy` → `remove individual cookies`

[image]

Comment: In FF 3.5, you'll want to use:
Edit -> Preferences -> Privacy -> remove individual cookies

Comment: In Firefox 4 on a Mac, it's still sort of as described above.

Comment: Too much work if you have to do it 5 times per minute while debugging something.

Comment: @romkyns Firefox allows you to keep the individual cookies window open whilst still working so you can just have it to a side whilst you work and refer to it and do what you need without having to go through the process above every time :)

Comment: [Paul's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5074931/33080) has worked great for me, except for clearing cache, unfortunately (but this answer doesn't address that either)

Comment: You can also use ctrl+F5 (Cmd+F5 on a Mac) to give a force refresh (ignoring cache and starting over).

Comment: In more recent versions, `Tools` → `Options` → `Privacy` → `remove individual cookies`

Comment: This is not addressing the cache issue which is more important. It's such a basic need really, even IE has it, I can't understand why it's not there in Firefox!

Answer (score 12):

There are two add-ons for FF that every web developer needs and they are [Web Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) and [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843), the Firebug extension [YSlow](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5369) comes in very handy too.

Web Developer Toolbar has great cache and cookie control down to individual cookies. Firebug lets you mess with the DOM and CSS directly for a page and YSlow is good for page weight and response times.

Be careful having Firebug enabled for JavaScript heavy sites as they really slow down. GMail will warn you about this and tell you to turn it off. I have had a problem trying to disbable sites with the menus when the tool is embedded in the browser at the bottom but opening it in its own windows the sites menu works fine.

I personnaly also like [IE Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1419) which means I can quickly view a page in IE without leaving FF and I can also get it to load anything that only works in IE with it.

Comment: Web Developer Toolbar has no way to clear the cache for a particular domain, it only has one generic button to clear all cache. I am not sure whether YSlow has any such option, please let us know if it does. The rest of your answer is kinda irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I have always wondered why my gmail is always slow (((( thanks a lot

Answer (score 6):

[Cookie Monster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4703) might work?.  Also, have you considered just using two [profiles](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Profiles) in Firefox?  You could setup two profiles with two icons and use one profile for the website and the other for the non-development.  The only problem would be you can only have one open at once.

Also, two browsers (Chrome, IE, Firefox, etc) might work well too.

Comment: That's  a good answer.... +1..using profiles help u a lot and cookie monster is a great add on..

Answer (score 6):

WebDeveloper extension allows to delete cookies for domain. It also can clear cache, although for me <kbd>Ctrl-F5</kbd> is enough usually.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and found a firefox addon to remove the cookies for the current site that you are displaying:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/remove-cookies-for-site/

Using that I don't have to navigate the firefox menus to find my site in the list (which was too time consuming).  This does not cover the cache-issue.  For that there is the Ctrl+F5 other people have mentioned.  It is covered in good detail here:

[What requests do browsers' "F5" and "Ctrl + F5" refreshes generate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385367/what-requests-do-browsers-f5-and-ctrl-f5-refreshes-generate)

Comment: Except if the page has an iframe - that iframe won't "see" Ctrl+F5 and still use cache. Argh!

Answer (score 4):

Best solution: 
1) Just Click **`CTRL+H`** and search the site. 
2) right click on it and choose **`Forget About this site`** 
(source: https://superuser.com/a/733154/249349 )

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to use firefox, clear cache and cookies for one domain and stay logged in (and retain cache) at other sites, you could run a second firefox profile concurrently using  the '-no-remote' parameter. I use this all the time to view sites I am building from an anonymous and administrative perspective at the same time.

One way to do this (in windows xp) is: make two profiles, then startmenu->run type 'firefox -profilemanager', untick the 'don't ask next time' box and load profile 1, then startmenu->run type 'firefox -no-remote' and load profile 2. You should now have two seperate firefox profiles running.

Answer (score 1):

Clearing cookies for a single domain is easy with any one of a number of tools.  Clearing the cache for a single domain or at the individual page level is sometimes useful, but hasn't turned out so easy for me thus far.

One specific situation is changing a meta redirect, where you can't just ctrl-F5 (you're being redirected, after all).  Using a different profile isn't an acceptable general solution.  Web Developer toolbar can disable the cache to test that the change is working but it's only a temporary fix, and not one that can readily be suggested to a client in order for them to view the change.

Comment: I think a meta refresh would still be amenable to Ctrl-F5. `302 Found` isn't (no request is ever sent), and that is a pain.

Answer (score 0):

I use [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5817) for firefox to remove single sites from cache. All you have to do is open places.sqlite in your user profile folder using this plugin and remove the site. It's not exactly an easy solution but it does work. Make sure you backup your profile 1st!

Answer (score 0):

Ross, I have the perfect answer for you.  Get on the current tab that you want cookies cleared.  Click tools > Page Info.  Or install [Page Info Forms & links](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7978) for a shortcut.  Then click the Security Tab.  Then View Cookies button. It will bring up all the cookies for the relevant domain.  Click the ones you want to delete, and click remove.

Comment: its a very looooong process,,,

Comment: Far from "perfect".  And it addresses only the cookies, not the cached resources.

Answer (score 0):

Seems we have cookies covered here.

As for cache, the trick is to make your development server force a refresh.
In httpd, you probably have some some cache directives to swap out for these:

```
   Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, must-revalidate"
   ExpiresActive On
   ExpiresDefault "now"
```

In header:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, no store"/>
```

The benefit of doing it the httpd way is that your scripts/images/css get refreshed.
In that way you are not restricting yourself to just browser with web developer toolbar, you can use other browsers such as chrome that does not do the no-cache thing so easily.

Answer (score 0):

Another extension that handles the **cookie** part of the question with a little more ease than the rest is [Close'n forget](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/closen-forget)

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/closen-forget

You can use it by toolbar button/context menu/keyboard shortcut in order to close the current page, discarding any cookies it held.
Optionally, the site can be removed from browser history and (again optionally) all the pages you visited in the current page can be removed from browser history too.

Answer (score -2):

Simple solution is simple - use two different browsers.
Say chrome for your email and Firefox for dev.

Also, you have [Cookie Swap](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3255). but it doesn't really work quite as smoothly as you'd like.