# CSS is not effecting immediately after change

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

In Visual studio 2008 I changed css methods (like font size increase). Which is not effecting when I run immediatly. If I publish to server. I can see changes. Why it is not happing in from VS 2008?

Thanks

Comment: Out of interest, what do you mean by "running". Do you mean building and running the actual application by pressing f5, or just saving and refreshing the already open webpage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably being cached by the browser. Try pressing Ctrl-F5 to refresh IE or Firefox.

Edit: for technical details see [What requests do browsers' "F5" and "Ctrl + F5" refreshes generate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385367)