# firefox F5 does partial refresh

Tags: firefox, refresh

I have a listbox and a html `<map>` element on my page. The list box has 50 state names of USA. and the `<map>` is a html `<map>` with 50 `<area>` elemnts over an image.
I have a functionality on my page. When you select a state from list box, the appropriate `<area>` element is highlighted using some jquery and javascript.

My problem is, when i click on the map and hit F5, the map is refreshed, but not the list box.
But when I do Ctrl+F5, everything is refreshed.

I'm not able to figure out why this partial refresh is happening on F5.

I observe this only in firefox(I have latest version). But not in IE or safari.

Comment: I can see how this will become a real problem if, in between page loads, Texas declares independence.

Comment: This should probably be moved to SuperUser.com.

Comment: @Jim Fell, this is a case of a developer trying to understand his application behavior, not a user trying to understand his browser.

Comment: Does the same web-app cause other browsers, like IE, Chrome, or Safari, to crash?  Make sure your browser is fully-up-to-date.

Comment: @JimFell.. It looks very much fine in other browsers. The issue is only with firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is defined behavior. F5 will reload the page including cached content; CTRL+F5 will force all content to refresh, including cached content.

**EDIT**

This page might help you out some more:
[What requests do browsers' "F5" and "Ctrl + F5" refreshes generate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385367/what-requests-do-browsers-f5-and-ctrl-f5-refreshes-generate)