# caching not working when refresh browser

Tags: java, image, caching, browser, refresh

I use image caching by reading a BLOB and then streaming using BufferedOutputStream. I set the following headers:

```
res.setHeader("Last-Modified", modDate);
res.setHeader("Expires", expTime.toString());
res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=31536000");
```

The caching works always except for the refresh button. If we load a page using menu click the images are loading from cache but if we click refresh button of browser it comes from server. Any idea?

Comment: the server should check the `If-Modified-Since` request header and send a 304 if appropriate; what server software are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different browsers deal with the refresh button differently.

You might want to check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385367/what-requests-do-browsers-f5-and-ctrl-f5-refreshes-generate/385491#385491).  Also, look at the headers to the request that is being sent to the server.  See if the browser is sending the If-modified-since header.

Actually, you might check all of the answers to that question.  For example, if you are using Firefox and initially did a Ctrl-(refresh) then Firefox won't cache it again until the browser is closed.

Comment: I tried with firebug. And saw that when I press press the menu button of the application there is no loading of images. And If I press refresh all the images are loading..I can see the If-modified-since in the request.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue like this.

get the date from req.getHeader("If-Modified-Since");
And compare the if-modified-since date and the date from database. If they are same then I return a status of 304. Then it won't be modified.

```
String modifiedSince = req.getHeader("If-Modified-Since");
    if(formattedLastAccess.equalsIgnoreCase(modifiedSince)){
        res.setStatus(304);
    }else {  // stream file }
```