# Disabled parameter on an input box: How is possible that I can change its value from Firebug?

Tags: asp.net, .net, view, user-input

This is a code, generated from my .NET 3.5 application :

```
<input type="text" 
 rel="0,00 €"
 id="ctl00_ContentPlaceBody_ImpostaCompravenditaImmobili1_txtRenditaCatastale"
 value="0,00 €"    
 name="ctl00$ContentPlaceBody$ImpostaCompravenditaImmobili1$txtRenditaCatastale">
```

Now, when I load it, and through Firebug (but this doesn't matter really, with whatever debugger you use you can do this) I add/delete (for example) `disabled=""`, and I refresh the page (by hitting <kbd>F5</kbd>), on the server side it *stores* this value. And in the page I get after the refresh, the value has been stored in the (I believe) context View of the page.

Is it a bug? Normal behavior? I found it really bizarre!

Comment: How do you *refresh* the page? By clicking the `submit` button?

Comment: no! F5 on the browser... submit can change the context. F5 must not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior doesn't depend on FireBug or a similar plugin. It depends on a browser.

I was able to reproduce this with my Firefox 10.0.1 (I also was able to reproduce this with earlier versions of FF): I added extra chars to my textbox, then pressed <kbd>F5</kbd> and the text in that text box wasn't changed. But after doing a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>F5</kbd> the value in my textbox resetted to the default value.

A simple test shows that FF set the `Cache-Control: max-age=0` header when <kbd>F5</kbd> is pressed.

Doing a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>F5</kbd> sent these headers: `Pragma: no-cache` and `Cache-Control: no-cache`.

I also was able to find a workaround for this on the  server side by using:

```
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

This will add  `Cache-Control: no-store` to the response headers (it means *do not store any part of either this request or any response to it.*).

For a breakdown of other browsers behaviour, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/385491/102112).

> Is it a bug? Normal behavior?

When I faced this first time it was really unexpected to me too.

Comment: Thank you for the explation! Get a -1 for this it is also good! Lol!

Comment: @markzzz, I suppose you got `-1` because the question was emotional, and hence a little bit unclear ;)