# When I do a cache refresh (ctrl+f5), my session dies

Tags: php, session

I built a function with login system, but when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> my session dies for the user. Can I change <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> settings?

Comment: This is a browser "problem". F5 is normally sufficient anyway.

Comment: That does not happen normally.  What browser are you using? Supply some of your php code so we can review for you.

Comment: More detail. Any relevant code? Browser? Etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should maybe try using cookies to manage your sessions. I also found this SO question describing the effect of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> on browsers:

[What requests do browsers' "F5" and "Ctrl + F5" refreshes generate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385367/what-requests-do-browsers-f5-and-ctrl-f5-refreshes-generate)

Answer (score 0):

The Ctrl+F5 is the refresh without "data". You can try using cookies for your sessions or try changing your "php.ini" configurations for session.