# Cached page never refreshed even with CTRL+F5 (even with clearing the browser cache CTRL+R)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I activate caching on my Visual Studio ASP.NET MVC4 project.

Here is the portion of code where I manage caching:

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1));
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
```

For testing I placed a breakpoint in the action Edit page. When I run my application and navigate to a specific page (an editing page) I can easily see that the action page is cached because the breakpoint is never reached. Next I cleared the cache with CTRL+F5 and navigate to the same Edit page. I expect to reach the breakpoint in my action Edit page but this is not the case. I never hit the Edit action page, never!?

[image]

[image]

Any idea why?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it's cached server side ? Also, nice answer on cache : http://stackoverflow.com/a/385491/971693

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the OutputCache attribute instead? It is simpler to control (done through config) and easier to use that writing to the response.

Example basic usage:

```
[OutputCache(Duration=10, VaryByParam="none")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Or you can create your own named settings in web.config. Example config:

```
<caching>
    <outputCacheSettings>
        <outputCacheProfiles>
            <add name="Cache1Hour" duration="3600" varyByParam="none"/>
        </outputCacheProfiles>
    </outputCacheSettings>
</caching>
```

...and used like this:

```
Example usage:

[OutputCache(CacheProfile="Cache1Hour")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Examples copied from [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs)