# Unable to refer external CSS

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I am trying to utilize a CSS file from a CDN on my site.master page. The CSS is located at `http://cdn.meriranchi.com/styles/site.css`. I have tried many variations of the below but am having no luck.

The site.master has the following markup:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>::MeriRanchi:: Ranchi ka search engine. Ranchi's 1st of its kind, City Search.
        Search for the shops, institutes , tourist spots , emergency services etc with ease.
    </title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <link  rel="stylesheet"  id="CssFile" runat="server"/>
          <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

In my code behind I add a href attribute to `CssFile`:

```
CssFile.Attributes.Add("href","http://cdn.meriranchi.com/Styles/Site.css");
```

The above renders the following HTML in IE9:

```
<head><title>
    ::MeriRanchi:: Ranchi ka search engine. Ranchi's 1st of its kind, City Search.
        Search for the shops, institutes , tourist spots , emergency services etc with ease.

</title><link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" /><link id="CssFile" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.meriranchi.com/Styles/Site.css" /><meta name="description" content="schools and colleges in ranchi,restaurants in ranchi,coaching institutes in ranchi,shopping complex in ranchi,shopping mall in ranchi,best cloth store in ranchi
best college in ranchi,best school in ranchi,showrooms in ranchi,authorised dealers in ranchi,grocery stores in ranchi,falls in ranchi,tourist places in ranchi,zoo in ranchi,tourist spots in ranchi,
schools and colleges, BIT Mesra, RINPAS, CIP Ranchi, Ranchi Mental Hospital, HEC, dams in ranchi, jagannathpuri rath mela, hadia, hadiya, hariya, morhabadi maidaan, firayalal chowk, 
" /><meta name="keywords" content="tourist places in ranchi, tourist spots in ranchi, business listings in ranchi, shops in ranchi, schools colleges in ranchi, restaurants in ranchi, movies in ranchi, jobs in ranchi,real estate deals in ranchi" />
</head>
```

Comment: Your link tag requires `type="text/css"`

Comment: i said i tried all possible tricks...

Comment: If you tried everything, then by that definition it's unfixable.

Comment: @Matthew : Not working....

Comment: Can you output the rendered HTML?

Comment: @Matthew: See my updated question with rendered html on IE9

Comment: Is this running locally or on a server? I realize you've tried "all possible ways," but have you tried just creating the link in HTML and not as a server side control?

Comment: Copying your outputted HTML works for me in IE9, could this be a networking issue on your end, or a caching issue?

Comment: @Matthew Do i need the media attribute???

Comment: No, the media attribute is only needed if you want to restrict what media types that CSS affects, by default the screen is included if you omit `media`.

Comment: @ahsteele Earlier it was a generic html control

Comment: @ahsteele : i tried it too... but no luck

Comment: @Matthew : i thinks its a caching issue bcoz on clicking the links its give a file site.cache to doownload instead of site.css

Comment: @AmitRanjan - If it's a caching issue, pressing `CTRL + F5` in the browser, to refresh the page, should load the page from the server.

Comment: @AmitRanjan have you used the IE dev tools to ensure that IE is making the request for the CSS file?

Comment: Ya its recieving... finally its working. I thinks its some sort of caching issue. I have used code in my Application_BeginRequest to clear all cache and now its working fine

Comment: @ahsteele plz post your comments as answer so that I can accept and close this one

Comment: @AmitRanjan posted an answer summarizing my comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than likely your browser thinks it already has a copy of your externally sourced CSS file. You can check this by watching the network request traffic in your browser's developer tools to ensure it is requesting a new copy of the file.

If the browser is not you should do a full page refresh by [pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/385491/61654).