# Forcing a full page load

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, webforms, pageload

I would like to do a full page load when I click a button which is unfortunately within a update panel.

I am okay to use onclick or onclientclick, which means I can use either ASP.NET or JavaScript to perform a full page load.

By full page load I mean the whole page (I know how post back works)

Comment: You could simply redirect back to the same page. This will do a new load - not a postback.

Comment: Not if you don't cache the page in the first place. If your page contains information that absolutely must be 'fresh' then you shouldn't be caching it.

Comment: Do you want to trigger the page load as if it was a new load or a postback? i.e. do you want the stuff inside `if (!IsPostBack){...}` to be ran on the page again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not use an anchor, you could style it to look like a button if needed.

staticly

```
<a href="SomePage.aspx">Reload</a>
```

or dynamically

```
<a href="<%=Request.RawUrl %>">Reload</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Triggers of your UpdatePanel. Especialy the asp:PostBackTrigger
 element might solve your problem like explained [there](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers)

Answer (score 0):

Let's call "full page load" a GET request.  GET requests can get cached.  We can bypass that cache with CTRL + F5 that allows a no-cache GET request.  In your case you need to perform a GET request with no cache and without requiring the user to hit CTRL + F5.

So setup the page with no cache.  Then you can fire off GET requests as expected.  However, caching behavior is both browser and server dependant (server can [ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385367/what-requests-do-browsers-f5-and-ctrl-f5-refreshes-generate) no cache), browsers are bugged/behave [differently](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222064).

Because of this Microsoft has a recommended way of setting up no cache:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="5">
<TITLE> Pragma No-cache </TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
This is an example of where to place the second header section<br>
so that the "Pragama, No-Cache" metatag will work as it is supposed to.<br>
</BODY>
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
</HEAD>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using response.redirect to the page itself if you really wanted to have a full page load.

Hope this helps.