# Firefox reloads cached PHP script. How to prevent such behavior?

Tags: php, apache, firefox, caching

Here are the request headers:

```
GET /url/ HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Cookie: data=ABC;
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

And here is response from the server:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 11 Oct 2013 23:28:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.18
Expires: Wed, 16 Oct 2013 03:28:32 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=360000
Pragma: cache
Content-Language: en
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 844
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=92
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

No matter how many times I refresh the page and no matter how, it always makes a request (which takes 200ms+ since it's over HTTPS). Am I overseeing something? Should the response headers contain more parameters in order to prevent Firefox from making a server request?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/385491/251311

Answer (score 0):

I normally do something like add `example.com/url/?nocache=<?php echo rand(); ?>` which will add a random  number to the url, making it a different url each time to prevent caching.

Comment: The OP does not want to _force_ a request and thereby bypass caching, he wants the exact opposite.