# What's the difference between F5 refresh and Shift+F5 in Google Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome

What's the difference between <kbd>F5</kbd> refresh and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> in Google Chrome browser?

The reason I ask is because sometimes when using <kbd>F5</kbd> on my site the pictures don't load properly but when using <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> the reload works.

Answer (score 220, accepted):

It ignores the cached content when refreshing...

https://support.google.com/a/answer/3001912?hl=en

> <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> = Reload the current page
>   <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> = Reload your current page, ignoring cached content

Comment: I wonder if it was because I said that it cleared the cache when refreshing, which isn't quite correct. I've updated my answer.

Comment: That page doesn't mention Ctrl + F5 anymore.  "Reload the current page, ignoring cached content  Shift + F5 or Ctrl + Shift + r"

Comment: According to a Community Expert on the [Google Chrome Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/dDn6qXfXoac): 

"... the Chrome shortcuts 'Ctrl + F5' or 'Shift + F5' doesn't reload the Chrome page anymore. The only options that work for reloading the page are Ctrl + r (which reloads the current page) and Ctrl + shift + r (which reloads the current page, ignoring cached content)."

Comment: @Mark D Worthen PsyD: F5 and Shift-F5 both still work for me using the latest version of Chrome (as do Ctrl-R and Ctrl-Shift-R) on. I tried on Win7 and Win Server 2008 R2 - will try on Win10 later. So much for experts!

Comment: Stupid question:  Does "Shift F5...ignore...cached" mean it Refreshes the Cached content as well? 
(I.e., it acts like you've never visited the page before)

Answer (score 26):

The difference is not just for Chrome but for most of the web browsers.

[image]

`F5` refreshes the web page and often reloads the same page from the cached contents of the web browser. However, reloading from cache every time is not guaranteed and it also depends upon the cache expiry.

`Shift + F5` forces the web browser to ignore its cached contents and retrieve a fresh copy of the web page into the browser.

`Shift + F5` guarantees loading of latest contents of the web page. 
 
However, depending upon the size of page, it is usually slower than `F5`.

You may want to refer to: [What requests do browsers' "F5" and "Ctrl + F5" refreshes generate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385367/what-requests-do-browsers-f5-and-ctrl-f5-refreshes-generate)

Comment: thanks for the response ... i know how to clear my cache ... problem is cached images only show up half way sometimes.. .was just curious.. thanks

Comment: The above is currently correct for Chrome and Firefox but not for IE11 (which responds instead to: F5 and Control-F5 and Control-R.

Comment: Does having F12 with disable cache (checked) also yield similar results?

Comment: What about cookies, are they part of the cached content?

Answer (score 9):

Reload the current page: 
<kbd>F5</kbd> 
 or 
 <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>



Reload the current page, ignoring cached content (i.e. JavaScript files, images, etc.):
<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> 
 or 
 <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> 
 or 
 <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

Comment: Yeah, I'm an infrequent user of Chromium (on FreeBSD), however I do sense that **Control-F5** _is_ amongst the effective shortcuts, despite its absence from Google's <https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179>.