# Why is this error appearing in chrome load resource: net::ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome

This is the error I am seeing in my Chrome's console.

> > load resource: net::ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR

How can I fix it?  I want to display a Google map

[image: CheckItHere]

Comment: Can you share your map code? Otherwise it's hard to help.

Comment: I am getting this issue for the last 2 days on all related google pages. It stumbles on search and youtube for me. I have been forced to "bing" (i.e. search - terrible) to figure out what was actually happening. The fix above seems to have fixed my issue (and allowed me to login with my g+ acct to post this). Thanks

Answer (score 119):

The error appears to occur when the QUIC protocol is blocked (e.g. by an ISP) along the route between you and the target site. As a workaround, to this error, you can disable QUIC in Chrome by disabling the `enable-quic` setting by navigating to:

`chrome://flags/#enable-quic`

And changing the `Experimental QUIC Protocol` drop down to `Disabled`.

[image: HowToDisableQuicProtocolInChrome]

Comment: My gmail and inbox and google developer site etc have been giving me trouble all day. I disabled that and bam. She works. Dono what google is up to. Dono if its just a coincidence that there was a chrome update today as well?

Comment: @Zapnologica I believe we have geographic location in common ... wonder if it isn't related to our archaic internet infrastructure?

Comment: @Zapnologica Have had similar issues, starting a few days ago, for many google services when using Chrome (but not when using IE or firefox). I also stay in S.A btw. Anyway, this solution seems to fit the case of it being a Chrome specific issue and is working for me so far.

Comment: This solution has also been mentioned on google product forums: https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/chrome/xKFfhDvhjU8/K9WurSs3LSUJ. This should probably be the accepted solution.

Comment: I'm visiting ZA and getting this same error on maps. ISP is MWEB, so I'm assuming it's a filter on their side. I see the same issue exists on Afrihost capped (MTN).

Comment: I just got this error on Chrome mobile running on Android phone. It happened twice when I was filling out a Google form.  Your suggestion seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks.

Comment: yeah...gamil & analytics and webmasters in trouble mode.. not loading because of same issue.... well thanks it solved my issue

Comment: chrome version Version 79.0.3945.88 (Official Build) (64-bit).  Disabling  QUIC Protocol provided (so far) immediate relief. For some reason, after disabling and relaunching, I needed to do the process again as it didn't seem to take the first time. Sometimes bugs are hard to squash. At this late date, I can only assume that our corporate network/firewall has changed to something that was at odds with QUIC Protocol.

Comment: I got this error yesterday and I got it in some Chromium based browsers (Microsoft Edge v86.0.622.56, Opera v71.0.3770.284). However Firefox work as expected. This answer solved the problem in all browsers!

Answer (score 15):

QUIC (Quick UDP Internet Connections) is a next generation transport over UDP, which aims to reduce latency (goal: 0-RTT connectivity overhead), deliver better multiplexing, introduce packet pacing, error correction, and more.

On the request the crypto maybe cached and the response refused to call

More info:

[www.youtube.com/watch?v=3dV_EPDSNSI](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3dV_EPDSNSI)

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=364381

Comment: Some firewalls may block QUIC communication, since it differs from "normal" TCP based HTTP comunication

Comment: Haha can't get to either your youtube or google links because of this issue.

Answer (score 8):

just press ctrl + F5 on browser page. Some local caching might be an issue. once you clear it, it should work.

Comment: [See this question for `F5` vs. `Ctrl + F5`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569394/whats-the-difference-between-f5-refresh-vs-shiftf5-chrome)

Answer (score 2):

In my case disabling of the QUIC (chrome://flags/#enable-quic) in Chrome didn't help. I saw this ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR in all browsers.

The solution wasn't in my computer but on the local network router. I have Synology RT1900ac router with parental control enabled and it uses web-filter for blocking danger or malware sites (in the default setting the basic level of the web-filter is set). And this **router's web-filter blocked googleadservices.com** webserver that Google uses for redirecting.

So the solution was just to **add googleadservices.com to the list of allowed domains** (see **Network Center > Parental Control > web-filter tab** on Synology router administration.)

If you have different router, you can have similer "web-filter" active and encounter the similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I get this when cache is disabled (due Paulo Mariano explanation). Just reenable it and will stop complaining about this and start getting google js sources.

[enable cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQKZS.png)