# Error appearing in chrome android only using datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, google-chrome-app

I have a website for renting cars. In the home page there is a formulaire where you can pickup your rent period (from date --> to date) and i use datepicker for that.

My problem is that my website isn't working on chrome android. I have the error below:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR

I tried to see chrome's console:
the problem should be that i can't pick a date. The field dosn't work in chrome app

---

***Remarks:*** 
It used to work fine in every other browsers, any suggestions ?

This is the error I'm seeing in my Chrome's console.

> Get http://mywebsite.com net::ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200 VM32:1

Answer (score 0):

The error appears to occur when the QUIC protocol is blocked (e.g. by an ISP) along the route between you and the target site. As a workaround, to this error, you can disable QUIC in Chrome by disabling the enable-quic setting by navigating to:

chrome://flags/#enable-quic

And changing the Experimental QUIC Protocol drop down to Disabled.

[Why is this error appearing in chrome load resource: net::ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28195610/why-is-this-error-appearing-in-chrome-load-resource-neterr-quic-protocol-erro)