# Django Admin ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: python, django, web, django-admin

Django Admin list view page for a single model returns a blank page. it only load some of the buttons. console shows this error **Failed to load resource: net::ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR**. Have been trying somethings but couldn't solve this one. Also it doesn't happen on local machine. I am using django jet. tried using the vanilla django admin but still the same error. Other than this model all the other model's list view page is working fine.
If anyone has faced this error in the past or know anything about it, suggest me some fixes. any help would be appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Comment: inside the page are you using some sort of map (google map, apple maps...)??
If not the problem is 99% cache related.

Comment: no we haven't used any maps and by cache do you mean the browser cache? tried it on icognito too.

Comment: heve you already looked at this answers ? [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28195610/14395688)

Comment: and the thing is that it was working till yesterday and we didn't make any changes. it just stopped working this morning.

Comment: yes i have looked at the answers u r talking about. None of them work for me

Comment: also the behaviour of the page is same on firefox but firefox doesn't show this error in console. and not any other error

Comment: if you made no changes the only possible thing left is the connection itself, maybe the ISP changed some parameters OR if you are using an entreprise PC and they made some changes to your browser... you could try to run it on explorer :)

Comment: no actually we have tried it with many different isps even different countries. it isnt accessible from UAE, Pakistan or UK. so i dont think its an ISP issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250092/discussion-between-mpizzotti-and-ibtsam-ch).