# base_url() echoing localhost path instead of live server path

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have an application build in CI 3.x version now i want to redirect to a specific directory in the root folder. i have an anchor tag through which i will redirect to the path now here is what i am doing!

```
 <a href="<?=base_url()?>ecommerce" class="shop-now-button">SHOP NOW</a>
//ecommerce is my directory name on root folder which contains the other website
```

now this is how the firefox is showing in inspect

```
<a href="http://clients.nextcrawl.ca/occ/ecommerce" class="shop-now-button">SHOP NOW</a>
```

which is the correct url! but what happens is when is actually click on it it takes me to the link **http://localhost/occ/ecommerce/** and i have no idea how and why it is doing this.one more thing the ecommerce directory has a wordpress site in it.

My question is not a duplicate because in other cases base_url() doesnot work or works incorrect whereas in my case the base_url value is correct its just not taking to the correct path

Comment: no it is not! my base_url is working just fine,you can see i even wrote the path of base_url, the issue is somewhere else,the issue is on clicking

Comment: Ok, so it should be an environment issue, not a CI problem, checked apache's vhosts?

Comment: vhosts? i have no idea what that is

Comment: please check config.php $config['base_url'] = ''; ??

Comment: already did its the correct path i am even echoing it in my question

Comment: Are you saying that `<a href="http://clients.nextcrawl.ca/occ/ecommerce" ... >` takes you to `http://localhost/occ/ecommerce/` when you click on it? If so, that's not an application problem; PHP is doing everything correctly if it's outputting the right URL in the href...

Comment: maybe you can check your `.htaccess` or your `server`. If there's no problem in you `base_url()` and that is not PHP, maybe look at your `.htaccess` or server configuration

Comment: it containes a wordpress site inside could that might be an issue?

Comment: Check the `.htaccess` of wordpress

Comment: Cache issue? Close all browsers and open in private window.

Comment: lol! @Tpojka i never thought this could be the issue! thanks man can you write it down as answer so i can mark it?

Comment: now this being done! one more thing how can i refresh/remove cache? because i did hard refresh(ctrl+f5) a dozens of times but it is still loading from cache

Comment: I've found Firefox's caching is kinda greedy - especially with static assets like css and js - `Ctrl + F5` isn't always enough annoyingly.

Comment: how to avoid it then?

Comment: Use Shift in combination. One more [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569394/whats-the-difference-between-f5-refresh-and-shiftf5-in-google-chrome-browser) in addition to those posted in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When environment is changed (eg. dev/pro/local) make sure that you have cleared browser cache memory so new values that are set by application are shown correctly.

All in all:

-Windows

```
Ctrl+F5
```

-MacOS

```
Cmd+Shift+R
```

Or use private browsing window.

Very useful links:

- [How do I clear my web browser's cache, cookies, and history?](https://kb.iu.edu/d/ahic)
- [What requests do browsers' "F5" and "Ctrl + F5" refreshes generate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385367/what-requests-do-browsers-f5-and-ctrl-f5-refreshes-generate)
- [Keystroke to reload a page without cache in Chrome for OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/391086/keystroke-to-reload-a-page-without-cache-in-chrome-for-os-x)
- https://superuser.com/questions/220179/how-can-i-do-a-cache-refresh-in-google-chrome

Comment: thanks tpojka! but there is still a problem i have tried ctrl+f5 dozens of time but it is still not woking and when i open it on private it works! can you recommend some code for the website to load always from server not from cache? cuz its a big website and it is in developement phase

Comment: Check those provided links. Also try with Shift in key combo.