# Deployed to Heroku - not seeing changes

Tags: github, heroku

I made a small, straight-forward change in my code - just changing the 'text' inside my circles.js function. All changes work locally, I committed, pushed, and merged to GitHub then manually deployed the master branch on Heroku, which says it was successful. However, I am not seeing the changes on Heroku that I can see locally. Any ideas of where I went wrong?

```
Circles.create({
            id: $(this).attr('id'),
            value: percent,
            radius: 50,
            width: 10,
            text: '<i class="'+icon+'"></i>',
            colors: ['#eeeeee', color]
        });
```

Comment: You can try reloading the page with [shift+F5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569394/whats-the-difference-between-f5-refresh-and-shiftf5-in-google-chrome-browser) to ignore the cached content.

Comment: Already tried that in various ways - it's not the cache