# Changes not updating in visual studio 2012 while debugging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am facing strange problem in `Visual Studio 2012`.
I recently moved from `Visual Studio 2010` to `Visual Studio 2012` I am using its web development feature with `asp.net`.

The problem actually is, sometime in debug mode it is not showing the change that I made in my code.
The thing is I added some `charts` and some `TextBoxes` according to the design which I was asked to make. But It was not updating the change when I open the page I developed from studio in debug mode.
Even it was not updating the changes I made to the `CSS`.

But when I open the page in the web browser directly the changes have actually been made!! But I was not able to see it from the studio's debugger.

I tried to search on MSDN but unfortunately couldn't find anything relevant to the problem I am facing.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with it?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that when you are debugging, your code was compiled with the latest changes.
I Recommend:

1. clean your solution in order to make sure you don't have any leftovers from previous builds
2. In your `configuration manager` make sure your project is being built for the configuration you are using.
   [image]
3. Make sure your code re-compiles before you run it.
   (**Tools** >  **Options** > **Projects and Solutions** > **Build and Run** > Set **On Run, when projects are out of date** to  `Always build`. Set **On Run, when build or deployment error occur** to `Do not launch`).
   [image]

Comment: Thanks, Every-time when I run my code I have the habit of rebuilding the solution. But still clueless..

Comment: @SPandya Are you making sure that the file with the changes is part of the re-build (step 1)? I also recommend cleaning your solution in order to make sure you don't have leftovers from previous builds.

Comment: Yes I am certain about it. And the changes you suggested are already there in place.

Comment: @SPandya how about trying to refresh the browser using [Ctrl + F5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385367/what-requests-do-browsers-f5-and-ctrl-f5-refreshes-generate) in order to make sure you do not get a cached copy?

Comment: No luck..Still stuck :(

Comment: @SPandya just for debugging, put a breakpoint on the modified file. is the Breakpoint being hit?

Comment: @SPandya I'm a bit rusty with ASP, but could it be that you are adding the control in the wrong event? Try adding it in the `Pre render` event, or in the same way/location you created controls that are showing.

Comment: Actually it didn't work for me.. I still get the old version of my javascript

Comment: @gayan1991 this does not apply to js files. js is a script is not being compiled and the reason your are getting your old code is probably because it is cached, Try using `Ctrl+F5`. take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385367/what-requests-do-browsers-f5-and-ctrl-f5-refreshes-generate):

Comment: @AviTurner I'm sorry but after that I found the error. It has to do with chrome. if you disable the cache. chrome updates as well