# Why jquery is not working in IE until click ctrl + F5?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am using jQuery, jQuery UI and other jQuery plugins like dialog or time picker.

Only in IE (all version) jQuery is not working at all. Once I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>, the dialog, date picker are working fine.

Other browsers are working without <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Are there any fixes available ?

Comment: Sounds like caching, and the fix is to hit CTRL-F5

Comment: **Ctrl + F5** Mystry solved for you here `:))` :P http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385367/what-requests-do-browsers-f5-and-ctrl-f5-refreshes-generate `CTRL-F5 is used to force an update, disregarding any cache. IE7 adds an "Cache-Control: no-cache", as does FF, which also adds "Pragma: no-cache". Chrome does a normal "If-modified-since" and Opera ignores the key.`

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your code in `$(window).load`.

```
$(window).load(function () {
   // run code
});
```

This will ensure that the DOM is ready and after that will run your code.

IE is a weird beast...

Comment: Hi Thanos,  Still it is not working  Forgot to mention that I am using smarty template and the jquery is included like the below code inside the .tpl (View file)  `{literal} 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function () { //My Code   });`