# running website locally wont updates images

Tags: image, visual-studio

So im making a website on Visual Studio 2013. I have a folder of images with images inside. It used to be another image but I changed my name so i overwritten the image with the new one.
The html is right, however when i run it it still shows the old image.
I thought maybe it hasnt updated or didnt overwrite so ive been adding it over and that didnt work. I also tried deleting it altogether and then adding it fresh and that didnt work.
Then I thought maybe the file path is wrong - no. definately right.
What should I do? Every time i run it, it showing the old image even though it doesnt exist anymore.

Comment: Did you try a hard refresh in your browser? (typically ctrl+F5, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385367/what-requests-do-browsers-f5-and-ctrl-f5-refreshes-generate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hard refresh was the answer for me, as Max said, typically Ctrl + F5. for me it was Fn F5