# Chrome not caching JSON responses

Tags: jquery, json, django, google-chrome, caching

I'm writing an AJAX based auto-complete and am trying to keep my server from being inundated with requests by using client side caching. The setup is as follows, Django serving JSON responses on the back-end, with the client using jQuery's AJAX routines to `GET` the appropriate data.

[image: request]

Looking at the response headers in Chrome, everything looks alright. The `Cache-Control` header is present, so I'm pretty sure that the problem is outside of Django's scope.

[image: response]

However, the server logs show that there was a request made to the API.

[image: logs]

**Code:**

This is the code I'm using to query the API.

```
function get(url, callback) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: true,
        url: url,
        success: callback
    });
}
```

**Misc:**

The little disable cache check-box isn't ticked, so Chrome *should* be caching responses.

**Edit:**

This is all set up in my development environment. So the server is serving from `127.0.0.1:8000`.

Comment: I've specified `Cache-Control: max-age=300, public, must-revalidate` in a tiny script and it caches fine. A minor note: make sure you're opening a page via clicking a link, otherwise (F5 or entering address) chrome specified `max-age=0` explicitly.

Comment: After further investigation, that's exactly what was happening.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chrome sends `Cache-Control:max-age=0` in case if you open a page using address bar or F5.

That's it - if you want to see it working go to that page by a link click.

Related but obsolete answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/385491/251311

Comment: Cool, going to the page via link seemed to return a cached response like I was expecting. This is one of the more request intensive parts of the API, so every little bit helps. Thanks!

Comment: I know this is an old topic, but if the OP's intention (and also mine) is to create a REST API for a localhost server or any other server to query from, how can we protect the API being flooded of requests if the API is not clickable? A HTTP form or javascript will have the same effect as clicking a link?