# Handling alert on Refresh in IE using selenium

Tags: java, internet-explorer, testing, selenium

I'm using IEDriver to test my webapp. My test is written in Java and driver is defined as following:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\Selenium\\IE\\IEDriverServer.exe");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

I'm facing the problem when the tests simulates F5 after form submission with:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.F5).perform();
```

As a result appears IE window saying:
[image]

I've tried to skip it by performing

```
actions.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).perform();
```

and

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

As I've understood, this window is not an alert, so driver can not switch to it. 
So is there any way to execute "Retry" in this window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java Robot utility can be used to click on the Retry button. Sample code is written below:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `F5`, then the page will refresh items which are modified, considers `cache`, so you will get warning.

Instead try reloading the entire page something like,

```
driver.navigate().refresh();
```

This will load the page without any warning. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385367/what-requests-do-browsers-f5-and-ctrl-f5-refreshes-generate) post will give you some insights.

Look for [Diff b/w F5 and navigate().refresh()](http://www.askqtp.com/2013/12/what-is-defference-between.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in my tests I have 2 possibilities. Test with `driver.navigate().refresh();` and with F5 too