# Problems with document.referrer

Tags: javascript, referrer

I'm having some trouble using document.referrer on some sites, even the reference site using HTTP protocol.

1. In what circumstances document.referrer may be empty (except HTTPS to HTTP)?
2. What is the best way to get the url reference only document.referrer?
3. In my site, document.referrer is empty, but when I look in Analytics website of references appears.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`document.referrer` is `not empty` if your site URL was clicked from other website, like from google search, from facebook, twitter, etc...

So, If someone opens your site from bookmark o directly types your site URL, `document.referrer` is `empty`.

Let's see these examples:

Click this link http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp you can see that document.referrer is `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28646433/problems-with-document-referrer`

If you search in google [`HTML DOM referrer Property`](http://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fprop_doc_referrer.asp&ei=k8HoVLjSBsvtaN_IgfgO&usg=AFQjCNFNiXvO_JozIUUi3Q7I2lHcJ18NhA&sig2=enaVBE1WVZvmxT-2x0-L-Q&bvm=bv.86475890,d.d2s), document.referrer will be `http://google.es/...`

And if you copy `http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp` opens new tab in your browser and paste it, `document.referrer` will be `empty`.

Comment: Good one . why document.referrer isn't empty when i give `ctrl+F5` or `F5` key .

Comment: Well, `CTRL + F5` and `F5` only refresh current document content, not HTTP meta-data, like headers, cookie, etc... Here is full explanation [http://stackoverflow.com/a/385384/3710490](http://stackoverflow.com/a/385384/3710490)

Comment: right ! any workaround to reset document.referrer when i reload same page . tough i see its a read only prop as per docs to set it manually . thank you

Comment: Nope. Only if you have designed a server, in `Response` object override http header

Comment: The referrer information can't be relied on, i.e. it can be turned off in some browser settings. It can also be explicitly set as anything by the client, like cURL:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-appleosx-bsd-curl-command-httpreferer/

Comment: Take note that in StackOverflow, the `nofollow` and `norefferer` tags are automatically added to links unless you're explicitly using the HTML `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try `window.frames.top.document.referrer` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
const referrerPage = document.referrer;

if ((referrerPage.indexOf(window.location.href) > -1) !== true) { // If referral is same page then page will not redirect.
    if (referrerPage.indexOf('viewplans') <= -1) {
        window.location.href = '/';
        return false;
    }
}
```

**viewplans** is the page name.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question, this simple script returns the URL of the site you arrived from:

```html
    <SCRIPT>
        document.write ( document.referrer )
    </SCRIPT>
```

see: [https://www.nku.edu/~manningd/javascript/referrer.html](https://www.nku.edu/%7Emanningd/javascript/referrer.html)