# Is it possible to get or store the previous redirect url?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm wondering is there any way to get the previous url of a redirect on the same domain?

I thought I could use document.referrer however, this is empty?

Is there any way of storing it in a cookie perhaps?

Cheers
KE

Comment: Cookies cannot be used cross-domain. So unless the redirect was on the same website, using cookies wouldn't be useful.

Comment: However, `document.referrer` should work. Are you using JavaScript to perform the redirect?

Comment: Oh ok, so you mentioned it being on the same domain. So in theory you could use cookies or even localStorage to see the previous URL.

Comment: Sorry for the spam. However, I just wanted to mention that I posted a working solution for redirects on the same domain. Check it out if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

So with plain JavaScript, you could do:

```js
// Sets previous URL before the page closes
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    localStorage["previous_url"] = document.location.href;
}

// Use this function to get previous URL
function getPreviousURL() {
    return localStorage["previous_url"];
}
```

Or with cookies:

```js
// Sets previous URL before the page closes
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    document.cookie = `pre_url = ${(document.location.href || "")}; path=/`;
}

// Use this function to get previous URL
function getPreviousURL() {
    var nameEQ = "pre_url" + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
            c = c.substring(1,c.length)
        }
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) {
            return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length)
        }
    }
}
```

You could use the `getPreviousURL()` function like so:

```js
var preURL = getPreviousURL();
// Sets variable to the previous URL
```

Basically, both of the examples above set the previous url by using the `window.onbeforeunload` event (which is triggered when the page is unloaded/closed). And, it gets the url by using `document.location.href`.

Assuming you're on the same domain, you can use the `getPreviousURL()` function to get the previous url.

I'm not sure why `document.referrer` doesn't work for you, although it's probably the best solution when you need to get the url cross-domain.

Comment: This didnt work for me for some reason the referrer is scrubbed out with this redirect, maybe something to do with opencart

Comment: Does the localStorage or Cookie solution work though?

Answer (score 0):

**document.referrer** doesn't work if the last url is another url.

ex. https://google.com -> https://example.com won't work.

> For security/privacy reasons, the Referer URL is stripped out when navigating from a HTTPS site to a HTTP site. It can also be deliberately stripped out via a variety of JavaScript and HTML tricks. There is no way to disable this behavior to get the Referer URL if it has been stripped.

> document.referrer is not empty if your site URL was clicked from other website, like from google search, from facebook, twitter, etc...

So, If someone opens your site from bookmark o directly types your site URL, document.referrer is empty.

Let's see these examples:

Click this link http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp you can see that document.referrer is [Problems with document.referrer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28646433/problems-with-document-referrer)

If you search in google HTML DOM referrer Property, document.referrer will be http://google.es/...

And if you copy http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp opens new tab in your browser and paste it, document.referrer will be empty.

> I'm wondering is there any way to get the previous url of a redirect on the same domain?

yes, **document.referrer**

Comment: Sorry I couldnt use this since Im using tag manager and it doesnt support this javascript