# Meteor won't start, everything is 'undefined'

Tags: meteor, meteorite

As I was testing some features I added to my website on the localhost version of Meteor, it suddenly broke. Here's a sample of the logged errors in my web browser console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Package is not defined meteor.js:21
Uncaught ReferenceError: Package is not defined json.js:21
Uncaught ReferenceError: Package is not defined base64.js:21
Uncaught ReferenceError: Package is not defined ejson.js:21 
Uncaught ReferenceError: Package is not defined reload.js:21 
Uncaught ReferenceError: Package is not defined tracker.js:21
```

There are about 142 other error messages just like the ones above, including "Template is not defined" for the templates in my project.

I decided to update Meteor to version 1.1.0.3 (was originally working on version 1.1.0.2) thinking that it would fix the problem, and yet the errors still persisted. Then I did a complete uninstall/reinstall with no luck. I even created a new project to test if the error was related to the actual code in my project or Meteor, and surprisingly enough, the errors persisted in the testsite (I simply typed into terminal meteor create testsite, than ran meteor in the new directory).

Any help would be much appreciate! I really can't do much work on this project with these errors. I apologize in advance if this is a simple-to-fix error, but I     am relatively new to using Meteor.

Comment: what's your OS? what did you do to uninstall meteor? did you delete `~/.meteor`?

Comment: did you try ```meteor reset``` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try a refreshing the page using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>f5</kbd>, which will also reload the cache.

I had the same problem. I restarted the server, refreshed, tried closing and reopening chrome and the problem persisted. However using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>f5</kbd> fixed the problem.

For more about refreshing see: [What requests do browsers' "F5" and "Ctrl + F5" refreshes generate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385367/what-requests-do-browsers-f5-and-ctrl-f5-refreshes-generate)

Note: I was using Chrome.