# IIS did not load the latest changes in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis

When I run the project, The web page loads normally but when I tried to make changes to the CSHTML files, I press refresh, and the page did not load the changes.
I have to stop IIS express and run it again to make the changes happen, which is very annoying and inefficient.

Microsoft visual studio 2015
Windows 7 32bit

edit:
My temporary solution that I have discovered: Save (even without changes) the applicationhost.config file, then save file im working on (to reload the page automatically using browsersync)

Comment: Clear the browser history..

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to understand how Caching works on IIS level:
When any ASP or ASP.Net page is requested, "Page Output Caching" stores a response of a dynamic page in its memory. But when any subsequent requests arrive for those pages,instead of re-processing the page,server sends the cached response.

Please check this [Link](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/caching). It should help you

Comment: I followed the how to on the link. The Administrative Tools doesn't have IIS Manager in it

Comment: In case of browser caching you can clear cache via code Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)

Answer (score 0):

did you set the "compilation debug" to false in your web.config?

If yes, set the debug to true. You should set this debug to false when deploy the web app.

Please refer to the page below:

[Why debug=false in ASP.NET applications in production environment](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/prashant_upadhyay/archive/2011/07/15/pros-and-cons-of-using-debug-true-in-asp-net-applications-in-production-environment.aspx)

Comment: the config file is already set to true. should I change it to false or it will just make it worse?

Comment: You should keep debug to be true in the config file. Have you tried to use different browser like Firefox?

Comment: I have used Firefox, IE and chrome. All of them doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I also came across this issue in a previous version of Visual Studio.
I noticed that my browser was caching the pages so I'm using ctrl+F5 when refreshing while debugging.

You can find more info on the difference between F5 and ctrl+F5 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385367/what-requests-do-browsers-f5-and-ctrl-f5-refreshes-generate)

Comment: Im currently using browsersync gulp for the reloading part and Im using chrome at the moment. I tried Internet Explorer. Still no luck.