# Cache doesn't get cleared in Angularjs application

Tags: html, angularjs

I have developed SPA application in Angularjs(version 1.6) and .net web api2, deployed on IIS server and it is working fine. Application has plain HTML files which gets loaded into ngView angular tag based on angular route changes. The issue I am facing is if I make any changes to html files and deploy the application, user doesn't see updated changes on html page when they use the application. The issue persists even if they clear the browser cache before logging into application. However they see updated changes if they visit the page and press "Ctrl + F5". I am clearing template cache using $templateCache.removeAll() when the application is launched but issue still persists. Can someone please help to fix this as users are getting annoyed because of this.

Comment: How are you deploying this? What hosting service are you using?

Comment: Please use cache busting

Comment: The browser does caching which is beyond the control of the AngularJS framework. See [MDN HTTP Reference - Caching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching).

Comment: @AJFunk I am deploying it on IIS web server with click once deployment of Visual studio

Comment: @harishr could you please tell me how to use cache busting. I am not aware of it

Comment: @georgeawg even if user clears the browser cache issue still persists

Comment: You stated that the problems goes away when the user presses ctrl-F5. **. Ctrl-F5 forces a cache refresh. See [What requests do browsers' “F5” and “Ctrl + F5” refreshes generate?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/385384/5535245).

Comment: @georgeawg yes problem goes away if user press Ctrl+F5. However if user manually clears cache (by going into internet options) and then logins problem remains

Comment: what build system are you using?? gulp? if yes you should use `gulp-rev`, if you are manually adding scipt js files in index.html then you should append it with query string.. just google `cache busting techniques` you will get the answer

Comment: @harishr I am not using gulp. js files are fine. I am talking about html files which I load in ngView using angular route.