# CSS changes don't do anything

Tags: css

If I'm working in my code with the browser open for about 5 min, everything is fine. Changes to my code updates after I refresh the browser.

But after some time my changes stop showing in the browser (even if I restart the browser). The only solution that works is, if I restart both the IDE and browser.

Is there anything I'm missing here?
Because I believe that this should not be happening.

PS.
This happens in both Visual Studios and Adobe Dreamweaver.

Comment: Please post your code; without it it is difficult to point out what the problem exactly is.

Comment: That's weird have you tried to refresh with ctrl + f5?

Comment: @Patte I also immediately thought about `Ctrl + F5` after reading this question. While I was trying to produce an answer, you made a comment :)

Comment: @TheDarkKnight It doesn't matter what my code looks like, because it have happened on almost every project I've worked with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But after some time my changes stop showing in the browser (even if I
>   restart the browser). The only solution that works is, if I restart
>   both the IDE and browser.

Try to use `Ctrl + F5`

For more information: [What requests do browsers' "F5" and "Ctrl + F5" refreshes generate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385367/what-requests-do-browsers-f5-and-ctrl-f5-refreshes-generate)

> Generally speaking:
>
> F5 may give you the same page even if the content is changed, because
>   it may load the page from cache. But Ctrl-F5 forces a cache refresh,
>   and will guarantee that if the content is changed, you will get the
>   new content.

Answer (score 1):

> PS. This happens in both Visual Studios and Adobe Dreamweaver.

It has nothing to do with Visual Studio and/or Dreamweaver, it's all about caching - related to your browser.

As mentioned above you can use `CTRL + F5` to force the browser to load your webpage from the network, not the cache. However, you can also use `Incognito Mode` in your Web Browser, it loads a fresh version as well, *but that's not practical to keep opening a new Incognito Window whenever you need to load the latest changes - I am just giving you a hint on a different solution that might help!*

I recommend taking a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922910/force-browser-to-clear-cache) - Published in 2009, fairly old but solid! - and it will provide you with MANY different possible solutions!